# Form application resolution in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dpi

I am developing an application using C# in Visual Studio 2013. After I finish designing a form and run the application, Form resolution becomes extremely bad. I test the app on 4k screen which could be the reason. the question is, is it possible to make my form application run with the same resolution as my screen

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar when I would create an empty forms project.

I started a new project and loaded the Xamarin Forms trial and the problem went away after I restarted.

I have seen the same behavior after I loaded a third-party charting component (something had broken power shell manager 4 also)

I repaired the installation and my forms resolution problem came back. 
I installed the Xamarin Forms trial again and it solved the resolution issue.

I have not seen this on VS2015RC.